# Trying to create an infinite for loop that can stop using function doIt()

Tags: loops, for-loop, infinite

Hey guys, I'm new to javascript and I'm doing a project for my final in class. I need to make it so this game engine I manipulated causes the generation button to go for an infinite loop.

I also need to stop it using (Reset==1). Any help? Here's the code I have so far if that helps:

```
function generation()
{

 for(y2=0; y2<2500; y2++) 
 {
  tempmapactual[y2]=mapactual[y2];
 }

 for (g=0;g<2500;g++)
 {
  neighbours=0;
  for (h=0;h<8;h++)
  {
   if (g+coords[h]>0 && g+coords[h]<2499 && mapactual[g+coords[h]]=="white.gif") 
   {neighbours=neighbours+1;} 
  }
  if (neighbours>=4 || neighbours==1 || neighbours==0) 
   {tempmapactual[g]="black.gif";}

  if (neighbours==3) {tempmapactual[g]="white.gif";}
 }

 for(y3=0; y3<2500; ++y3) 
 {
  if (mapactual[y3]!=tempmapactual[y3])
  {
   mapactual[y3]=tempmapactual[y3];
   document.images[y3+offset].src=mapactual[y3];
  }
 }

} 




</script> 

<script>
function doIt()
{
   for (i=0; i<X; i++)
  {
    // This is where I have trouble. What part of generation() do I call?
  }

     if (Reset==1) break; // This will kill the loop instantly.
  }
}
</script>

<script>
window.onload(doIt($(X).value)));
</script>


<form> 
<input type="button" value="generate" onClick="generation();"> 
</form>

<form>
<input type="text">
</form>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Infinite Loop!" onclick="doIt();"> 
</form>

<form>
<input type="button" value="Reset" onclick="doIt();">
</form>
```

Comment: I read the function name in the title as "dolt" and thought you trying to be a funny guy.

Comment: Haha, unfortunately not. Is The Simpsons still on television anymore!?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not multithreaded and you cannot break out easily of an infinite loop. Most browsers/JavaScript will detect out of control spinning and kill execution.

If you are writing a game engine, a better use of your CPU cycles is to set a timer. That way you can stop the timer when it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't break out of an already-running infinite loop from another function without threads; but you could take a slightly different approach: if your "infinite loop" happens by way of the function running one iteration and then using a `setTimeout` callback to call itself again after an interval, then it'll run 'continuously', while still being interruptable (by, say, setting some global flag variable in your `doIt` function, which `generation` can check when it's invoked, and exit if it's true.

Comment: So, my professor gave us the wrong code then... awesome! Haha, thanks for the insightful responses, everyone! I love this site!

Comment: How would you go about doing this if the generation() is activated via onClick. I'm not sure if clearTimeout can be called via onClick, which is what my professor expects.

Comment: You don't need to clear the timeout; just set a global var in doIt (`var continue = false;`), and then at the top of `generation()` you put in `if (!continue) return;` - next time `generation` gets called, it'll just exit, and it won't set another timeout callback for itself either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at [this article](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/timers) about timing delays. Whenever JavaScript is busy going calculates (including with `generate()`) it is unresponsive to button pushing and such.  You want to limit how much that happens.

Comment: That article was extremely helpful! However, instead of using window method, would I be able to attach this setTimeout to an onClick?

Comment: @JoeOzz Anything you can do in standard code you can do inside an onClick callback